# Calculating average days (with DateDiff and NULL)

Tags: ms-access, null, average, datediff

MS ACCESS (Jet-SQL)

I want to find the mean difference between two dates, in days. However one date contains NULL values which I want to exclude from the calculation. Please note I can't use the `WHERE` function because I actually have other aggregate calculations in my `SELECT` statement (not shown here) which I don't want to filter.

My last attempt:

```
    SELECT
        Avg(Iif(dateDischarge IS NOT NULL, DateDiff('d',DateValue(dateRandomisation),(DateValue(dateDischarge))),NULL)) AS dtdis_dtrand

    FROM Table
    GROUP BY Variable
```

Thanks for any help,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

To exclude from the calculation you need to exclude the rows from `AVG()` as currently the `0` has an affect.

Exclude them from the `SELECT`:

```
... FROM Table WHERE dateDischarge IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex. For simplicity I removed my other SELECT statements from the example above. I actually don't want to exclude any cases from my other aggregate functions, therefore WHERE function would be unhelpful in this case.

Comment: Try using NULL instead of 0 in the IIF?

Comment: Same error msg: "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"... I know the DateDiff statement is working correctly on a non-grouped query, and this produces #ERROR in the rows where dateDischarge=NULL